Can you assign variables in Google Sheets?
I'm trying to figure out a way that I can (essentially) make it so when I update a cell, it will take the info in the cell and transfer the old info to a new cell.
Example:
We have three cells: A1, B1, and C1. A1 contains 1,000 and B1 & C1 contain 10. But then we change A1 to 1,500. I want B1 to then be 1,000 while C1 stays 10. Then, again, if we update A1 to be 3,750, I want B1 to become 1,500 and thus C1 to become 1,000. A1 --> B1 --> C1.
I figured this would be easier done with variables because currently, whenever a cell is updated, the rest are updated at the same time.
I tried the tried and true IF statement but that proved not to be fruitful as when A1 was updated, B1 and C1 just turn into A1... I tried goofing around with the iterative calculation speed but I want to use this idea throughout the doc and it would change other values. I tried looking into the LET function but I don't think that would serve the purpose I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated! I'll look into the Apps Script if I need to, but any direction would be lovely :)

I'm not sure if this can be done using Google Sheets, but this looks like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Our company needs to keep track of our past 3 expenses for a given project. Rather than having to update each cell each time we get a new expense, I wanted to find a way to cut out some of the chaff.


I'll look into the Apps Script if I need to…

Yes, you could use a simple onEdit event handler.
function onEdit(e)
{
  curr = e.range;
  if (curr.getA1Notation() != "A1") return;     // do nothing unless A1 edited
  next = curr.offset(0, 1);                     // next = B1
  next.offset(0, 1).setValue(next.getValue());  // copy B1 to C1
  next.setValue(e.oldValue);                    // copy old A1 value to B1
}

